# Convert my php code into shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I have this type of 8 block of `<div>` so I want to convert it into shortcode :

```
<div class="homebx01 clearfix ani-1">
        <div class="homebxhead clearfix">
          <div class="bxicon homebxicon01"></div>
          <div class="bxheadtxt">Category name</strong></div>
        </div>
        <div class="cl"></div>
        <div class="homebxbody clearfix">
          <ul class="bxulsty">
            <li class="clearfix"><span></span> <strong>Category Description</strong></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="cl"></div>
        <a class="morebt clearfix" href="#">Link to particular Categories post.</a> 
</div>
<div class="homebx01 clearfix ani-1">
        <div class="homebxhead clearfix">
          <div class="bxicon homebxicon01"></div>
          <div class="bxheadtxt">Category name</strong></div>
        </div>
        <div class="cl"></div>
        <div class="homebxbody clearfix">
          <ul class="bxulsty">
            <li class="clearfix"><span></span> <strong>Category Description</strong></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="cl"></div>
        <a class="morebt clearfix" href="#">Link to particular Categories post.</a> 
</div>
<div class="homebx01 clearfix ani-1">
        <div class="homebxhead clearfix">
          <div class="bxicon homebxicon01"></div>
          <div class="bxheadtxt">Category name</strong></div>
        </div>
        <div class="cl"></div>
        <div class="homebxbody clearfix">
          <ul class="bxulsty">
            <li class="clearfix"><span></span> <strong>Category Description</strong></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="cl"></div>
        <a class="morebt clearfix" href="#">Link to particular Categories post.</a> 
</div>
```

Help me that how  to convert my this php code into shortcode to add in the page?

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: I see no PHP in your code, just plain html, what research have you done so far?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode ?

Comment: I already gave you your php code to work from. Why you don't want to use it and modify is as I suggested to fit your html output needs, .... Well, it is up to you. The code that you supplied is totally meaningless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basics of creating a shortcode are quite simple. You just need to create a function that returns the code you want to output in a string and register that function:

```
function wpse_143641_homebox_shortcode( $atts ) {
  return <<<HOMEBOX
<div class="homebx01 clearfix ani-1">
  <div class="homebxhead clearfix">
    <div class="bxicon homebxicon01"></div>
    <div class="bxheadtxt">Category name</strong></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cl"></div>
  <div class="homebxbody clearfix">
    <ul class="bxulsty">
      <li class="clearfix"><span></span> <strong>Category Description</strong></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="cl"></div>
  <a class="morebt clearfix" href="#">Link to particular Categories post.</a> 
</div>
<div class="homebx01 clearfix ani-1">
  <div class="homebxhead clearfix">
    <div class="bxicon homebxicon01"></div>
    <div class="bxheadtxt">Category name</strong></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cl"></div>
  <div class="homebxbody clearfix">
    <ul class="bxulsty">
      <li class="clearfix"><span></span> <strong>Category Description</strong></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="cl"></div>
  <a class="morebt clearfix" href="#">Link to particular Categories post.</a> 
</div>
<div class="homebx01 clearfix ani-1">
  <div class="homebxhead clearfix">
    <div class="bxicon homebxicon01"></div>
    <div class="bxheadtxt">Category name</strong></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cl"></div>
   <div class="homebxbody clearfix">
    <ul class="bxulsty">
      <li class="clearfix"><span></span> <strong>Category Description</strong></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="cl"></div>
  <a class="morebt clearfix" href="#">Link to particular Categories post.</a> 
</div>
HOMEBOX;
}
add_shortcode( 'homebox', 'wpse_143641_homebox_shortcode' );
```

Further examples and details about how to accept aguments and such are available in the [Shortcode_API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) codex docs.

Comment: Thnk u very much.. its working.. (y)